# Do Git operations on web server or on local filesystem?

Tags: wordpress, git, web

I'm new to web development. I have a repo at GitHub where I manage my own theme for wordpress. What is the best way for handling this theme? Is it okay when I do the Git operations (clone, pull, push) directly on the webserver or should I sync the theme folder with a local repository and do all the Git operations on my local file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you. There is no a better way. Depends of what are you more confortable using. Doing the Git operations in the webserver, it will execute the same commands that you would run in your local folder. Another option for you, it can be to install a client for Git, like TortoiseGit, that is easy to use.

Comment: Thank you. When I clone a git repo, where does git save the log in data? Maybe clone and push a git repo can be a saftey risk, because the log in data is in the theme folder, maybe?

Comment: No, the credentials that you use to clone and push the data in your environment there are not saved in the folder. So is not a problem at all to work locally with your git repo. The user that you use is showed in the client, but not the password.
Please if the answer is helpful for you, you can accept the answer which can also benefit for others who has same puzzle with you and we could archive this thread. Also, feel free to leave comment below if still has any puzzle about it:-)